# karate - Missing Data from method when using nested Embedded Expressions

Tags: karate

I've been trying to build a payload using nested Embedded Expressions. This is an example of the feature file:

```
Feature: missing part of the payload

Background:
    * url 'http://localhost:9090'
    * def localDateTime = Java.type('java.time.LocalDateTime')
    #* def time = localDateTime.now().plusHours(2)

@ignore
@reuse=CreateDog
Scenario: Create Dog
    * def payload =
    """
    {
    "name": '#(dogName)',
    "age": '#(dogAge)',
    "adoptionData": '##(adoptionData)'
    }
    """
    * print payload
    When path 'createDog'
    And request payload
    And method Post

Scenario: Create Dog From Table
    * def time = localDateTime.now().plusHours(2)
    * def adoptionData = 
    """
        {
            "tutor": "Any Name",
            "adoptionDate": '#(time)'
        }
    """
    * table createDogPayload
        | name      | age | adoptionData |
        | 'my dog'  | 33  | adoptionData |
    When def result = call read('this:embededExpressionMissing.feature@reuse=CreateDog') createDogPayload
```

I want the Adoption Data to be Not Mandatory and that is why it has the '##(adoptionData)' in the payload. The value for the adoptionDate is generated by the time variable defined previously.

When I run the test the payload is printed with the right values but the request is sent without the time in the adoption date. Please check the print bellow.
[Karate testing logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxfmI.jpg)
Maybe I am doing something wrong here. I tried a few combinations but none of them fill the date as I am expecting.